# Is there a cleaner way to write this?

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

I was able to figure out this project from the Helsinki MOOC course, but I think there is a cleaner and easier to read way to write it. The goal was to print out:

```
*****
*
***
****
**
```

And here are the directions: "Complete the method public static void print arrayInStars(int[] array) in the class named 'Printer' to make it print a row of stars for each number in the array. The amount of stars on each row is defined by the corresponding number in the array."

My code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // You can test the method here
    int[] array = {5, 1, 3, 4, 2};

    printArrayInStars(array);
}

public static void printArrayInStars(int[] array) {
    // Write some code in here
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {

        while (o < array[i]) {
            System.out.print("*");
            o++;
        }

        i++;
        o = 0;
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Is there a  more elegant way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your code. However, since you want another way of doing it, given below is a more compact one ([using for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 5, 1, 3, 4, 2 };
        printArrayInStars(array);
    }

    public static void printArrayInStars(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int o = 0; o < array[i]; o++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
*****
*
***
****
**
```